# Where are generic class declarations in the C# grammar?

Tags: c#, generics, grammar

I was trying to find the production in the C# grammar (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664812(v=vs.71).aspx) for a generic class declaration but was unable to find it.

There is only the following production for class declarations:

```
class-declaration:
attributes(opt)   class-modifiers(opt)   class   identifier   class-base(opt)   class-body   ;(opt)
```

As you see, there is no section for type parameters and for `where` clauses; right after the class name (`identifier`) starts the `class-base` production.

So where are type parameters and the `where` clause lurking in the C# grammar?

Comment: Keep in mind you're looking at an older version of the C# spec where generics did not exist.

Comment: @BoltClock: Where can I find the new one? This was the first hit on google.

Comment: You can download it from http://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=7029 or find it in your VS installation directory under VC#/Specifications/1033.

Comment: @BoltClock: Thanks, why is it no longer provided as web page?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine ;)

Comment: I will leave the question open; maybe I am not the only one who is looking for a spec with generics on the web. Feel free to post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the C# 5.0 spec, the grammar for the `class-declaration` production is introduced in section 10.1:

> ### 10.1 Class declarations
>
> A *class-declaration* is a *type-declaration* (§9.6) that declares a new class.
>
> ```
> class-declaration:
> attributes(opt)   class-modifiers(opt)   partial(opt)   class   identifier   type-parameter-list(opt)   class-base(opt)   type-parameter-constraints-clauses(opt)   class-body   ;(opt)
> ```

Here, you can see `type-parameter-list` and `type-parameter-constraints-clauses` (where the `where` keyword appears). The grammar for each of those productions can be found in sections 10.1.3 and 10.1.5 respectively.